# How to get values associated to a javascript dictionary

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom-events, javascript-objects

I have this declared dictionary variable inside a script tag in a html page.
I would like to get the values associated to the "Roads" and "Intersections" keys. Theses values change every time the page is refreshed. Catching them, will allow me to change these colors on my python folium map using Javascript :

`(geo_json_cae0ea33c63e4c438678d293e5c32c0d.setStyle({'fillColor': "#FF0000", 'color': "#FF0000"});`

Following suggestions, I tried this but I couldn't have the expected result.

```
var layer_control_aec3ac6e0e424b74a19b4c9d1c78ffeb = {
            base_layers : {
            },
            overlays :  {
                "Roads" : geo_json_cae0ea33c63e4c438678d293e5c32c0d,
                "Intersections" : feature_group_1c28eff59e394734be54cf676a09eae1,
            },
        };


window.onload = function() {
  for (var name in this) {
    if (name.includes("layer_control_")) {
      for(let key in this[name]) {
        console.log(key, this[name][key])
        
      }
    }
  }

};
```

I got lots of things in the console except what I want (the values of overlays dictionary)

Comment: Why don't you access the properties directly? such as ```layer_control_aec3ac6e0e424b74a19b4c9d1c78ffeb.overlays.Roads```?

Comment: @ikhvjs I assume that the variable name is generated by the backend and changes on reload.

Comment: How? The variable is changing evrytime  except "Roads" and "Intersections" keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can't access `layer_control_aec3ac6e0e424b74a19b4c9d1c78ffeb` directly (because the name changes on reload), you can access the variable from within `window`:

```js
var layer_control_aec3ac6e0e424b74a19b4c9d1c78ffeb = {
    base_layers : {
    },
    overlays :  {
        "Roads" : "geo_json_cae0ea33c63e4c438678d293e5c32c0d",
        "Intersections" : "feature_group_1c28eff59e394734be54cf676a09eae1",
    },
};


window.onload = function(){
    for (const name in this){
        if (name.includes("layer_control_")){
            let { Roads, Intersections } = window[name].overlays;
            console.log(Roads, Intersections);

            // Roads.setStyle({'fillColor': "#FF0000", 'color': "#FF0000"});
            // ...
        }
    }
};
```

Your initial approach with `for (var name in this)` was correct. 
However, `name` only contains the name (string) of the variable, and not it's value.